# Creating a list of values of the same index from another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I was wondering how you can create a list of values of the same index from another list, when the amount of values is not known beforehand.

for example I have the list

```
list = [[25,75,94,63],[55,13,0,99],[41,63,93,25]]
```

I want a second list that would be

```
[[25,55,41],[75,13,63],[94,0,93],[63,99,25]]
```

If possible I would like the answer to only use simple python functions and without the use of importing a module. And if possible how to do so using a loop (probably nested?)

Thanks

Comment: The "zip" function can help here. It produces tuples which must be converted back to lists then. A loop can do that. You should show your own effort and code (properly formatted in the question) to solve it.

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese Of course it can also be done without "zip".

Comment: This is *transposing* the lists. In other words, inverting the rows and columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
a = []
for j in range(len(list1[0])):
    a.append([i[j] for i in list1])
```

Here is a one-liner:

```
[[i[j] for i in list1] for j in range(len(list1[0]))]
```

This gives the output:

```
[[25, 55, 41], [75, 13, 63], [94, 0, 93], [63, 99, 25]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) builtin function which does precisely what you'd expect.